# How to centre and change font colour of pandas dataframe caption?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]How do I centre the caption of my d15N_model dataframe and make the caption font black instead of grey using pandas .style.set_caption() styler function?

```
d15N_model = d15N_model.style.set_caption("d15N Model Fixed Effect Statistics")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dictionary of your preferred caption style:

```
Styles = [dict(selector = "caption", 
               props = [("color", "black"), 
                        ("text-align", "center")])]
```

Then set these `Styles` in `set_table_styles`:

```
d15N_model = d15N_model.style.set_caption("d15N Model Fixed Effect Statistics").set_table_styles(Styles)
```

**PS** you can set other HTML properties such as `background-color`, `font-size` and `font-family`.